# Как выводить список ul в ширину, а не длину?

Tags: html, css

Собственно, хочу сделать, чтобы сам список отображался в ширину (вправо), а не в длину (вниз).

Помогите, пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо! :-)

```
<div id="topMenu">
     <ul>
          <li class="firstMenuItem">ГЛАВНАЯ
          <li>ЗАПРОС
          <li>ДОСТАВКА И ОПЛАТА
          <li>О НАС
          <li class="lastMenuItem">КОНТАКТЫ
     </ul>
</div>

#topMenu {
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 980px;
    min-width: 980px;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #445566;
}

#topMenu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Скриншот моего: http://clip2net.com/clip/m0/df83f-clip-4kb.png?nocache=1

Скриншот, как хочу: http://clip2net.com/clip/m0/1f326-clip-9kb.png?nocache=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Используйте свойство `display: inline-block` для `li`
2. HTML5 - это хорошо, но хорошим тоном будет теги закрывать, хоть это и не обязательно.

P.S. с inline-block появится некоторое расстояние между `li`-шками, поэтому для `ul`:

```
font-size: 0;
line-height: 0;
```

А для `li` установить нужный `font-size` и `line-height`

Comment: Не согласен с тем, что хороший тон закрытие тега li.

Comment: @soledar10 обоснуйте тогда уж.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/8cksLmvh/

HTML

```
<div id="topMenu">
     <ul>
         <li class="active"><a href="#">ГЛАВНАЯ</a>
          <li><a href="#">ЗАПРОС</a>
          <li><a href="#">ДОСТАВКА И ОПЛАТА</a>
          <li><a href="#">О НАС</a>
          <li><a href="#">КОНТАКТЫ</a>
     </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#topMenu {    
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #ccc;
    width: 980px;
    min-width: 980px;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #445566;
    height: 50px;
}
#topMenu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
#topMenu ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
    vertical-align: top;    
}
#topMenu ul li a{
    display: block;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #445566;
}
#topMenu ul li.active a{
    color: #fff;
    background: #000;
}
#topMenu ul li a:hover{    
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```